# Tournament Search In Chessbase Online

Tags: software, chessbase

How do I search for games from a specific tournament in ChessBase Online? For example, to see games from the United States Championship, you have to search for "USA-ch". How would anyone know to search for "USA-ch", as that does not seem intuitive at all? I stumbled on this abbreviation by accident. Is there a better way, or somewhere that shows the abbreviations ChessBase uses?

Comment: Someone voted to close this question due to it not appearing to be about chess within the scope defined in the help center. The fourth paragraph of the topics entry appears to permit this software question: https://chess.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic "Other, less specifically chess-related subjects may also be on-topic, depending on how chess-related the specific Q&A is. These gray-area questions include topics of etiquette, psychology, software, books/articles/media, as well as other subjects. Chess-specific questions about programming a chess engine or other chess software are welcome."

Comment: Sorry if my question was out of line for this forum. Can you tell me of a better place to post my question? Or if it just needs to be closed or taken down, no problem. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think that it's out of line for this SE at all, SteveF. I left the comment there to indicate the contrary: that it does indeed seem to be in line with the current Help Center definition. I left the comment (with quoted material) for others' consideration in voting to keep it open or close it.